# Running BitCoin Wallet On USB

Tags: wallet, portable

I'm trying to run a BitCoin wallet on a USB Drive. I've got that working, but I'm trying to make the block chain get downloaded and stored inside of the USB drive as well. This is the only thing I've been able to come up with and I've had no success.

```
H:\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -datadir=H:\Bitcoin\appdata
```

I get the error "Filename is incorrect". I know there is a portable BitCoin program, but I'm also wanting this to work for other coins such as LiteCoin, and I know there aren't portable versions for those.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's just an issue with the code block, but I only see one double quote. I assume that the other is before the entire code block, and is used to pass the program name.

The only other possible issues I can think of are to

- make sure the directory specified in the datadir argument exists and is writable
- make sure that the USB drive is mounted on H:\ on any other computers you use. Maybe it would be smarter to use a relative path instead.

**Regarding portable Litecoin etc.**
Any program is portable, as long as all of its dependencies can be met in a portable environment. Therefore, if you copy the entire `C:\Program Files\Litecoin` folder, you should, *in theory*, have a portable program, provided you copy your data directory also, or don't mind re-downloading the blockchain and don't mind losing all your Litecoins.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at electrum. It offers the ability to have a portable wallet like your looking for.  It's a thin client modrl Bitcoin client utilising a random seed phrase which can be used you restore your wallet anywhere with or without ypur wallet file on a usb.  Electrum also allows you to have the same wallet open and in use multiple locations something which the standard client does not support.